# Unwanted white space at the bottom of mobile version website, only when website's width is greater than viewport

Tags: html, css

There are a lot of similar questions already asked. But I still couldn't figure out the problem.

When viewing the site on mobile there is this unwanted white space, desktop version does not have this problem.

Somehow, the unwanted white space is only present when width of website is greater than viewport(again, only on mobile).

The code is below.

```css
 *, *::after, *::before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        border: 2px dashed rebeccapurple;
      }
      
      html,
      body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: fit-content;
      }
      
      .myDiv {
        height: 2000px;
        width: 2000px;
        border: 2px dashed tomato;
        margin: 25px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use px ? Probably you set height as 2000px so your site isn't responsive. Or you need some reset for css because browser set it's own base css. Try to search on google about reset css

Comment: @Sfili_81 I think the problem is with a meta tag missing. But I'll give your solution a try.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I used a css reset It didn't work. Btw I used this css reset -> https://piccalil.li/blog/a-modern-css-reset/

Comment: Does it happen in every browser?

Comment: @Adriano, I dont know I didn't check on any other browser. I am only focusing on chrome browser right now!

Comment: I can tell you it does not happen in Firefox :)

Comment: @Adriano The issue is consistent with firefox! I just downloaded firefox and checked.

Comment: It might just be the rendering from the devtools. It seems to me the content is shrunk (at least in my chrome try), the rendered page on a small screen shows the red divs smaller than 200px. Thus, I believe it is rendered scaled down even though the viewport itself is still filling the whole window.

Comment: @Adriano The problem is not dev tools. I opened the site on a mobile device, chrome browser, the problem is till there. I think it is related to scaling of site on mobile version.

Comment: Uhm, do you want a responsive web site? so set max-width:2000px and width:100% for example

Comment: Also, using devtools i found a margin:25px on your divs, this cause your white space `div {
        margin: 25px;
        background-color: tomato;
      }`

Answer (score -1):

Try set .div1 width to 1000px on style

Comment: why? Please add more explanation

Comment: Because when the width is too large, on the phone when displayed, it will overflow the screen. In my opinion, the .div1 width should be set to 1170px

Comment: The white space is still there! Also I want that div to be 2000px.

Comment: try to remove cache in browser or open incognito tab then see the result (should be set to 1000px)